# Gaussian blur without using opencv

Tags: python

Is it possible to Gaussian blur an image without using opencv in Python? I'm doing the following but since it's the only thing I perform in my code, I'd prefer to avoid it and not use the opencv library at all.

```
res = self.cv2.GaussianBlur(a, (0, 0), sigmaX=2, sigmaY=2, borderType=self.cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: You """just have to""" reimplement the [Gaussian Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) on your own in python.

Comment: Is it possible?
Yes. I have done this before in MATLAB for an assignment. You basically create a gaussian kernel and perform the 2D convolution operation on your image using your kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with the following:

```
import skimage
res = skimage.filters.gaussian(a, sigma=(2, 2), multichannel=True)
```

PS: I do not understand the negative votes at all.